# VB XML query on attributes using LINQ

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to learn LINQ and have a question on querying XML using VB.

My XML:

```
 <Procedure-Text>
    <A ID="marker1"></A>Do This Procedure
 </Procedure-Text>
 <Procedure-Text>
    <A ID="marker2"></A>Do That Procedure
 </Procedure-Text>
```

How can I specify my query to get only the procedure text that has the ID attribute **marker2**? In other words, I would like a resulting string that says *Do That Procedure*.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use VB XML literals:

```
Dim marker2 = From x In data...<Procedure-Text> _
              Where x.<A>.@ID = "marker2" _
              Select x
```

The triple dot syntax produce "all descendants" of an xml element, i.e. `data...<Procedure-Test>` will produce a list of `<Procedure-Test>` tags inside `data`

The dot syntax on XML literals means "first descendant" so `x.<A>` will produce the first occurence of `<A>` inside x. Of which x is now instance of `<Procedure-Test>`

And now that you have the desired `<A>` element, comparing its id to a string is trivial with the `@attr` attribute selector. `<A>.@ID = "marker2"` will evaluate to `True` if the ID attribute of the `<A>` tag is equal to "marker2"

So `x.<A>.@ID` means "The ID attribute of the first `<A>` tag inside x"

And you want the `<Procedure-Text>` element, so you specify `Select x`

Full example:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim data = <doc>
                   <Procedure-Text>
                       <A ID="marker1"></A>Do This Procedure
                   </Procedure-Text>
                   <Procedure-Text>
                       <A ID="marker2"></A>Do That Procedure
                   </Procedure-Text>
               </doc>

    Dim marker2 = From x In data...<Procedure-Text> _
                  Where x.<A>.@ID = "marker2" _
                  Select x

    ' prints the second procedure-text element
    Console.WriteLine(marker2.FirstOrDefault().ToString())

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

Comment: Works! Thanks!
Instead of FirstOrDefault, I use Value to get the string I need.

Comment: VB does have lots of support for xml that C# (my language of choice) is lacking.  Its the only thing about VB I wish was in C#.  I also didn't know that this support extends into duct-typing on XElements.  Its pretty remarkable compiler magic.

Answer (score 1):

The linq query is

```
from x 
in d.Descendants("A") 
where x.Attribute("ID").Value == "marker2" 
select x.NextNode
```

In other words, look for an element named A where it's ID attribute is "marker2" and take the immediate next node.

You'll probably want to do a FirstOrDefault() on the resulting enumeration to get out the XNode (its actually an XText) that has your text in it.